# Restoring a sitefinity site from production to local

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sitefinity

I am trying to perform an upgrade and in order to do so, I need to restore my production site on a local machine, upgrade the site and deploy back to production.

The process for restoring the site sounds straightforward but I think there are some steps/configurations I am still missing.  This is what I have done so far:

1. Downloaded the website files, saved them on local under C:\inetpub\wwwroot
2. Downloaded the database full backup (.bak file) and restored it in MS SQL Server Management Studio
3. Changed the Connection Strings to:

`<connectionStrings>
<add connectionString="Data Source=MSSQLSERVER;Database=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" dbType="MsSql" name="Sitefinity" />
</connectionStrings>`

But that didn't do it and I am getting a **Server Error in '/' Application** Runtime error.

What did I miss? My first guess is the Connection String not being setup properly. Do I need User ID and Password in the string if the database in local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If integrated security is false you should provide userId and password so that the app can connect to the sql server.

This is a good place to start:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Veselin, that makes sense. I'll check out the website, thank you. On another note, if I want to perform an upgrade, I don't really need to setup the site on local in IIS, correct? I can import it in Project Manager and to upgrade the site.

Comment: Yes, correct. Then you need to build it and eventually test it, for which you'll need proper DB connection string as Sitefinity needs to perform database upgrade as well.

Comment: The SF upgrade is new to me. While the project is still in project manager, I can still open it in visual studio to built it, correct? All my test sites in project manager have .mdf databases but I restored this database backup in SQL server management studio. I think the first step, as you said is a proper connection string to perform database upgrade as well. I'll try again tomorrow. Thank you for the tips. Are you with Telerik?

Comment: Yes, you can build it with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to verify the connection string, check the configuration.

SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services -> Verify SQL Server is running, properties on SQL Server -> Host Name / Name should be verified under service.

Besides verifying the connection name, [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/1232833.aspx?Server%20Error%20in%20Application%20) post has a lot of good information for you to try.